# Is it secure when a HTTPS web application transmit data through a wireless devices such as iPAD?

Tags: https, wireless

A HTTPS web application encrypts data transport between the browser and the web server. When this HTTPS app is used on the browser in a wireless mobile device such as iPAD, the data transmission is still encrypted or not?

Wireless transmission encryption is another thing if compared to HTTPS, correct?

Stock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you said the data is encrypted between the browser and the web server. The encryption will hold until the web browser receives the traffic. After that you are relying on the security of the web browser and the device the web browser is on (an IPad in this case) to protect your data.

And yes wireless transmission encryption is a layer on top (or below depending on how you look at it) of HTTPS. These two encryption schemes are applied at different protocol layers. Wireless transmission encryption is only applied between your access point (AP) and your device so you still need HTTPS to protect you between the server and the AP.

Comment: If the wireless network employs cryptographically strong wireless encryption standards such as WPA2, you will then have one more layer protection over the HTTPS. If the wireless network does not employ WPA2 or any other standards, the data is just purely protected by HTTPS. In this case, do you think the data transmission is still secure? Stock.

Comment: Your data is encrypted with https whether or not you have wireless security. If you are concerned about wireless security then you can use a VPN as your extra layer and VPN into a location where you trust the transmission security (such as you main office). This will give you extra security between the AP and the VPN server.

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). Knowing the OSI model will help understanding how devices interacts with software and vice-versa.

**EDIT**
@Stock The content of the data contained in the web page is secured by HTTPS protocol. If no protection is added to the wireless configuration (i.e. WPA, WEP, etc.) it only means that the  packet wrapping the HTTPS packet won't be encrypted. The data from the web page is still encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

here is a commonly cited statement, and even more often implemented approach "We are using SSL to protect all communication, we are secure". At the same time, there have been so many articles published on the topic of "channel security vs. token security" that it hardly makes sense to repeat those arguments here. Therefore, listed below is just a brief rundown of most common pitfalls when using channel security alone:

```
It provides only "point-to-point" security
```

Any communication with multiple "hops" requires establishing separate channels (and trusts) between each communicating node along the way. There is also a subtle issue of trust transitivity, as trusts between node pairs {A,B} and {B,C} do not automatically imply {A,C} trust relationship.

```
Storage issue
```

After messages are received on the server (even if it is not the intended recipient), they exist in the clear-text form, at least temporarily. Storing the transmitted information at the intermediate aggravates the problem or destination servers in log files (where it can be browsed by anybody) and local caches.

see more :

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Services#Communication_security